# Problems referencing resources in jsp

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp

I couldn't achieve a functional reference scheme to my example application as follows. File teste.js seems not being reached by the resource declaration in jsp file. Any help could be valuable.

jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title> Composição </title>

            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://localhost:8080/compo/resources/js/teste.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
    Greeting : ${greeting}

    <table><tr><td id="save"> clique </td></tr></table>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("save").onclick = function fun() {
                //alert("hello"); - working
                testing("hello 2"); //not working
            }
        }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

teste.js

```
function testing(message){
    alert('messaged script: ' + message);
}
```

I am using Spring MVC and I've build the application in Eclipse, using its wizard, and for this reason it is using a "WebContent" folder structure, in spite of the fact that I have turn my project into a Maven project after creation. I think this is an important information.

**UPDATE**

After several tests, I concluded that the problem is in the Web-MVC configuration, because a similar project without Spring performs the access to resources perfectly.

Configuration (Spring 5.0.2):

```
package com.mycompany.compo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.compo")
public class SpringConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean

    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("public", "classpath:/resources/")
          .setCachePeriod(31556926)
          ;
    }


}
```

Comment: Why are you not using relative path to your Javascript file?

Comment: @tsolakp, actually I have been trying every kind of configuration, using relative paths, page contexts and anything is working.